# Is there a way to tie Cargo into IntelliJ's build system?

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

I just started with the [Rust plugin for IntelliJ](https://intellij-rust.github.io/). When I click "Build/Build Project" or "Build/Recompile xxx.rs", I only get the message

```
Compilation completed successfully in 709ms
```

However, nothing was compiled since I don't get any error messages on "broken" Rust files. When I click "Run/Run...", IntelliJ starts Cargo and I see an error message.

Is there a way to tie Cargo into IntelliJ's build system?